# Roslaunch fails to set MASTER_URI over ssh

Tags: master, ros-master-uri, ros-fuerte, ssh, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've read [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12434/using-roslaunch-to-run-distributed-systems-over-ssh/) and set my MASTER_URI accordingly (own machine name) yet the remote node gets launched with another roscore.

Here is my launch file

```
<launch>
    <machine name="Panda" address="LabRob-Panda-01" user="panda" default="false" env-loader="/opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh"/>
    
    <!-- send roomba urdf to param server -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py /home/erupter/Apps/ROS/simple.urdf" />
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="laser"/>
    <param name="use_rep_117" value="true"/>
    
    <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="tf" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 10" />"

<!--    <node pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" name="jsp"/> -->

<!--    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" name="laser" >
            <remap from="tf" to="laser" />
    </node> -->

    
    <!-- Hokuyo Base Node-->
    <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_laser" machine="Panda"></node>

    <!-- Rviz Node-->
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d /home/erupter/Apps/ROS/hokuyo/hokuyo_node/hokuyo_test.vcg" name="rviz01"> </node>
</launch>
```

And here is the result of the launching

```
erupter@FCD-04-Ubuntu:~/Apps/ROS$ echo $ROS_MASTER_URI 
http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:11311/

erupter@FCD-04-Ubuntu:~/Apps/ROS$ roslaunch hokuyo.launch 
... logging to /home/erupter/.ros/log/ce7b5b28-6584-11e2-96a3-e0cb4e8e9c06/roslaunch-FCD-04-Ubuntu-32673.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:57645/
remote[LabRob-Panda-01-0] starting roslaunch
remote[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: creating ssh connection to LabRob-Panda-01:22, user[panda]
launching remote roslaunch child with command: [/opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh roslaunch -c LabRob-Panda-01-0 -u http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:57645/ --run_id ce7b5b28-6584-11e2-96a3-e0cb4e8e9c06]
remote[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: ssh connection created

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /tf_prefix
 * /use_rep_117

MACHINES
 * Panda

NODES
  /
    hokuyo_laser (hokuyo_node/hokuyo_node)
    rviz01 (rviz/rviz)
    tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [32695]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:11311/

setting /run_id to ce7b5b28-6584-11e2-96a3-e0cb4e8e9c06
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [32708]
started core service [/rosout]
process[tf-2]: started with pid [32722]
process[rviz01-3]: started with pid [32735]
[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: launching nodes...
[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: auto-starting new master
[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: process[master]: started with pid [28756]
[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: setting /run_id to ce7b5b28-6584-11e2-96a3-e0cb4e8e9c06
[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: process[hokuyo_laser-1]: started with pid [28770]
[LabRob-Panda-01-0]: ... done launching nodes
```

I also tried setting an env like so

```
<node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_laser" machine="Panda"> <env name="ROS_MASTER_URI" value="http://FCD-04-Ubuntu:11311"/>

</node>
```

But it doesn't work.
Distro is fuerte on both machines.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53174/roslaunch-fails-to-set-master_uri-over-ssh/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is covered in detail in [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/36600/how-to-tell-remote-machines-not-to-start-separate-roscores-when-using-roslaunch-fuerte-regression/).

Problem is ros_comm version together with actual shell variable.
Updating ros_comm and correctly setting the env variable ROS_MASTER_URI corrects the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0